# Android rotating multiple bitmaps around a point

Tags: android, bitmap, rotation

I am rotating a set of bitmaps on canvas around a certain point. I am using following function to rotate:

```
private void rotateGroupdAtPoint(ArrayList<MyBitmap> group, int degrees) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        float minx=100000,miny=100000,maxx=-100000,maxy=-100000;
        for(int i = 0; i < group.size(); i++) {
            MyBitmap m = group.get(i);
            if(minx > m.getX()) {
                minx = m.getX();
            }
            if(miny > m.getY()) {
                miny = m.getY();
            }
            if(maxx < m.getX() + m.getBmp().getWidth()) {
                maxx = m.getX() + m.getBmp().getWidth();
            }
            if(maxy < m.getY() + m.getBmp().getHeight()) {
                maxy = m.getY() + m.getBmp().getHeight();
            }
        }

        float x = (minx+maxx)/2;
        float y = (miny+maxy)/2;
        Log.d("minmax","min:"+minx+","+maxx+"    max:"+miny+","+maxy);


        for(int i = 0; i < group.size(); i++) {
            Log.d("position before","x:" + group.get(i).getX() + ", y:" + group.get(i).getY());
            float newx = (float)(((group.get(i).getX() - x) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(degrees))) + ((group.get(i).getY() - y) * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(degrees)))) + x;
            float newy = (float)(((group.get(i).getX() - x) * Math.sin(Math.toRadians(degrees))) - ((group.get(i).getY() - y) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(degrees)))) + y;
            group.get(i).setX(newx);
            group.get(i).setY(newy);
            group.get(i).setBmp(rotateBitmap(group.get(i).getBmp(), -90));
            Log.d("position","x:" + group.get(i).getX() + ", y:" + group.get(i).getY());

        }
    }


private Bitmap rotateBitmap(Bitmap bmp, int degrees) {
        if (degrees != 0 && bmp != null) {
            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

            matrix.setRotate(degrees, (float) bmp.getWidth() / 2, (float) bmp.getHeight() / 2);
            try {
                Bitmap rotatedBmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight(), matrix, true);
                if (bmp != rotatedBmp) {
                    bmp.recycle();
                    bmp = rotatedBmp;
                }
            } catch (OutOfMemoryError ex) {
                return null;
            }
        }
        return bmp;
    }
```

Firstly I am finding the mid point that is common to all bitmaps then rotating around that point. Currently I have no issue with orientation, I will add code to do that as well. But my problem is that bitmaps are not rotating properly at the desired angle around the center point. Can anyone guide me where I am wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You're not rotating the bitmaps at all.  You use the `setX()` and `setY()` properties to move the bitmaps to their new locations.  On top of that, you need to decide what degree they should rotate and use the [`setRotation()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setRotation%28float%29) method in conjunction with the [`setPivotX()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setPivotX%28float%29) and [`setPivotY()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setPivotY%28float%29) methods.

By default, `setRotation(float radians)` will rotate the image in `radians` around the center point of the view you are rotating. So if you call `group.get(i).setRotation(Math.PI/2)`, your bitmap will rotate 90 degrees from the point it is at.

You can adjust the point at which it rotates by calling the `setPivot()` methods.

```
View view = group.get(i);
view.setPivotX(0);
view.setPivotY(0);
view.setRotation(Math.PI/2);
```

This will rotate the `view` around the top-left corner to a perpendicular angle.

Comment: I have mentioned that I will add orientation code later. I have added it well as. you can see that in question. I have updated the code. Still having the problem.

Comment: Are they simply not rotating at all or just "around the desired point"?

Comment: Also, why not rotate the View as described instead of rotating the bitmap?  You're creating a brand, new Bitmap every time you call this.  From what it sounds like, you're calling this a lot.

Comment: Actually I am using a class that is extending from View. This class has to draw multiple bitmaps on its canvas. The requirement is that in some situations, I have to rotate some bitmaps around a point that is the center among them. Actually, if I have a image of divided into 4 pieces, two of them rotate properly but other don't. I have attached a sample image explaining the issue. Also it is not rotating around the center as well.